# <itemBody xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"></itemBody > how avoid xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" in output XML

Tags: xslt

I am converting XHTML to XML in QTI format(qti.xml). My XSLTcode is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" exclude-result-prefixes="x" >

<xsl:template match="x:div[@id='item']">

        <itemBody>

            <p class="direction"><xsl:apply-templates select="x:div[@id='directions']" /></p>
            <p class="supplemental-elements"> <xsl:apply-templates select="x:div[@id='supplemental-elements']" /></p>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="x:div[@id='options']" />

        </itemBody>
    </xsl:template>
```

After execution I am getting `<itemBody xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">` .I want only `<itembody>.`  I am also using exclude-result-prefixes="x".  But its not helping .Could u please help me.

Ambadas More

Answer (score 1):

Well if you remove `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` from the `xsl:stylesheet` element the problem should be solved. Why do you have that? Do you need to create some elements in the XHTML namespace?

Comment: Thank you Martin. But my XHTML is having is    ----<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
 If i remove that xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" from Stylsheet element. In output i am getting----><p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Which coin is missing?</p>. Means now this attribute is coming in all tags of itembody